# form not showing properly in MDIParent when formborderstyle is set to FixedSingle

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010)

I have set the formborderstyle to FixedSingle and Maximize the Form from Code

```
With Form1
   .MdiParent = MdiParent1
   .BackColor = FormColor
   .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
   .Show()
End With
```

When I have tested it in Windows Xp Everything is fine
But in Windows 7, The Form's Corner Hide With the MDIParent, so the Menustrip and StatusStrip of form is not showing properly.

If the User Minimize and Maximize the Form in Windows 7 then all is fine.

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: This is a somewhat minor flaw in Winforms, it forgets to throw an exception when you do this.  MDI only supports child windows with a resizable border.  You cannot make this work, change the FormBorderStyle back to Sizable.

Comment: @HansPassant, Ok I got it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[ClientSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.clientsize%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** property, this will avoid the different sizes on different OS's

Comment: How I can use it for Display Form??